# Add an image (nparray) to a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I created an empty dictionary in python.  I'm reading images and processing them in a loop and after processing, the result is a numpy array.  I'd like to add the nparray to the newly created dictionary and store a sequential integer as they key, and the array as the value.  How do I get started?  In the end I'd like to add these processed images to an imagegrid for display in my jupyter notebook and have code to do so if they are in a dictionary.

Maybe there's an easier way to do this?

```
stopsign_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_stopsigns.xml') 

img_dict = {}

folder = "D:\\temp\\"
for imagesdir in os.listdir(folder):
    imgName = imagesdir
    img = cv2.imread(folder + imgName)

    signs = stopsign_classifier.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor= 1.01, minNeighbors = 9)

    #check if stop signs exist in the photo
    if signs is ():
        print("No stop signs found")
        # Draw a box around stop signs that were identified based on the return info from the stop sign classifier
    else:
        for (x, y, w, h) in signs:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255, 255 , 255), 8)
            
    # code for adding img to the dictionary here
```

Comment: *I'd like to add the nparray to the newly created dictionary and store a sequential integer as they key* , mmm this to me sounds like a list.

Comment: please review [mre]. I highly doubt all the OpenCV stuff is relevant to your question about basic python programming (nor required to reproduce the issue). -- further, please review [help/on-topic]. this site is the wrong place to ask for help learning to program. consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ -- I'm only seeing this question because you tagged it "OpenCV". it's not. I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'd like to add the nparray to the newly created dictionary and store a sequential integer as they key* to me sounds like a list, where elements are already indexed with consecutive numbers.

If you want to use a dictionary:

```
#init empty dictionary
img_dict = {} 
img_n = 0

for imagesdir in os.listdir(folder):
    # your code

    # update dictionary
    img_dict[str(img_n)] = img
    img_n += 1
```

Then you will access any element of the dictionary like this

```
img_dict["3"] ...
```

However, if the linear incremental access is exactly what you want, consider using a list:

```
#init empty list
img_list = []

for imagesdir in os.listdir(folder):
    #your code

    # update list
    img_list.append(img)
```

Then you will access any element of the list like this

```
img_list[3] ...
```